# iOS 7 - Scroll not working on UITableView subview of MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, mapkit

I have a map view to which I add a callout subview. This subview has a UITableViewController.

When I try to scroll this table, the map scrolls instead.

I tried other views instead of the table view, like button, switch or slider, but none seem to respond to inputs and all the inputs go to the map view.

The code that adds the subview is the following:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{

        CustomCallout *calloutView = (CustomCallout *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCallout" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        CGRect calloutViewFrame = calloutView.frame;
        calloutViewFrame.origin = CGPointMake(-calloutViewFrame.size.width/2 + 15, -calloutViewFrame.size.height);
        calloutView.frame = calloutViewFrame;

        [view addSubview:calloutView];

}
```

How can I enable scroll in the table view inside the CustomCallout?

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling the scroll of the map when the callout appears, and then re-enabling map scrolling after it disappears:

```
mapView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work. The map stays static but the table won't respond to touches.
Thanks for your answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work but try doing something like this on your cellForRowAtIndexPath in your tableview:

```
for (int z=0; z<[theNumberOfRowsInYourTable]; z++) {
    mapView.tag = z;
    mapView = ((MKMapView *)[mapView viewWithTag:mapView.tag]);
}
```

then:

```
mapView.scrollEnabled = No;
```

Or like this:

```
for (int z=0; z<[theNumberOfRowsInYourTable]; z++) {
    mapView.tag = z;
    mapView = ((MKMapView *)[mapView viewWithTag:mapView.tag]);
    mapView.scrollEnabled = No;
}
```

I didn't try it though, I just conceptualized it, hope you get an idea.